# SQL Databases on more than one computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

I'm writing a desktop program that allows you to view customer information, as well as adding, removing, editing etc. It's to be installed onto a friends computer. The database will be stored locally on one computer. Only one user will be able to access the database via the desktop application.

If I were to publish it, and attempt to run it on another computer, would it work? Or would that computer also need SQL Server on it?

Comment: depends on the database...but yes, probably.

Comment: For example, the program (c#) uses a database to store customer information.

Comment: I'm new to programming..
But I'm attempting to have a form that allows you to view customer information, as well as adding, removing, editing etc.
What I'm trying to understand is, if I were to publish it, and attempt to run it on another computer, would it work? Or would that computer also need SQL on it?

Comment: Thank you, you have lovely people here.

Comment: I edited my previous comment, if that makes any more sense to you.

Comment: If you're new to programming, it's better to get insight into what you want to achieve, what you need to know and what skills you need to develop. Don't start with asking silly questions on programming groups, your question is very unclear and too general to answer it.

Comment: I copied the comment into the question... And winforms, SQL (as in the title..) And I haven't tried anything I was just asking for future reference.

Comment: I did research, but found it easier to just ask. What I'm trying to get across is, do I need to install SQL on the machine I plan to use the program on, as I'm building it on a different machine.

Comment: As regards to the data in the database, as you can imagine it will be empty until the user has started inserting data, but the column names, data types etc, would they need to be created from scratch on that machine?

Comment: I see, and I'd have to have to set up the database connection again, as it will differ from where its located on my computer, I presume I can develop a sort of "setup wizard" and select where the database is stored?

Comment: @Tom "I did research, but found it easier to just ask." This site is meant to help people who are willing to help themselves out too.  If you are looking to go far in the programming world I would suggest you change your approach to solving problems.  Just some "friendly" advice.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a hypothetical situation that is hard to answer in its current form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about a desktop application. If this is so, you can provide your application to someone else and have them use it. However, there are different points that you need to consider:

1. Where will the your code reside?
2. Where will the database reside? Is there 1 shared copy or will each user has his own? This has a major effect on the ease of installation and the cost of your application.
3. If the database is shared, do you have a Server to host the database where all users will logon to?
4. Does the database have a max. number of users (limit/meter)?
5. Will the database be behind a firewall?
6. How many copies of the database need to be purchased?

Comment: Yes I'm talking about a desktop application, that is being built on my computer, to be installed onto a friends computer. And the database will be stored locally on one computer. Only one user will be able to access the database via the desktop application.

Comment: So one of your machines have to act as a server for the database. The other computer would need to have a connection to that PC. Many databases such as SQL Server and Oracle allow access to database via special ports but you have to adjust your firewall settings to allow for this to happen which is a security risk. This model is not common a more common mode is to have a server separate from users machine. Cloud computing offer an attractive alternative.

Comment: Alternatively I could have the database stored on the computer where the application is going to be used?

Comment: Yes. You would have 1 machine with db and code and the other machine with code only.

Comment: Before you invest time and effort in full blown application, try the concept with a tiny program first.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you just use the most basic database connection options then either the other machine will need to have sql installed, or the other machine will need to have network access to the database running on your server.

If your application is intended for a corporate intranet having a single DB server running on the network is probably an acceptable solution.  For anything else it probably isn't.

If your users need to share data I'd recommend hosting the data on a server yourself and exposing it to the end user as a web service instead of a raw database connection.

If your users don't need to share data, look into compact databases intended to be embedded in applications.  Since you're using C# I'd recommend SQL Server Compact because it speaks the same flavor of SQL as Microsoft's larger database products.  The other major player in this space is SQLite; which is dominant outside of the Microsoft stack.